# Proper CakePHP model to natively use multiple select and "dynamic" multiple select (e.g. tags)

Tags: php, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many, multiple-select

In my schema Test *HABTM* Variable (originally I used hasMany but I found more documentation using HABTM even though it seemed overkill to me).

I want to use a multiple select in a CakePHP form and I don't want to have trouble saving, retrieving and pre-filling the data (ie. ugly array manipulations in beforeSave and beforeFind, extra queries for retrieving the selected options and other things that may cause me to lose my hair even earlier than I probably will anyway).
One usecase is a multiple select where the options are known beforehand,
the other one needs to allow for creating new and deleting old options (I'm using select2).

With the help of `cake bake` and some [model HABTM documentation that was I missing](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-related-model-data-habtm) when I read the FormHelper documentation I found out that

1. I have to name my multiple select form field like the model that belongs to it i.e. Variable.
   It's implicit in the FormHelper documentation, but definitely could be highlighted more.
2. Also implicit: Because the `find()` operation gets the possible values for a field, I had to call the fields in my Variable model `id` and `name` (how else would it know from the Model name in the input call what to display). I can change `find`'s options but that broke the convention at some other step I think.
3. Inconsistently if I want to supply a list of possible values in the controller, I have to set a variable that is lowercase, camelized and pluralized (not uppercase and singular like my Model and like I have to name the form field, not lowercase, underscore-separated and singular like my name field and my table).

I thought I didn't need to set the possible options in the controller (because I either know them or they're added on-the-fly by the user, I don't really want to populate the DB with them beforehand), but I tried to wrap my head around the convention. I could not get it to work unless I populated the DB with them beforehand and set them in the controller.

That seems fragile or at least more narrow compared to the treatment of single selects.

### My continuing problems

1. With HABTM I can't create new options on-the-fly (it's okay for one usecase, but not for another, which is more like tagging).
2. With HABTM I don't want to have to populate the DB with options. And I don't really want to set the options in the controller, but in the view (because I anticipate this will cause problems with multiple "Tests" on one page, if it doesn't then it's okay).
3. With HABTM it doesn't work when I change the `Form->input` to `Form->select` (doesn't really matter, but adds to that feeling of my solution being fragile).
4. With hasMany I got as far as automatically selecting values I filled in in the DB, but it does not destroy or create associations (i.e. delete no longer selected options in the child table, even though it is declared as dependent). I think here it's due to the fact, that I don't properly pass the IDs of the child table, but how would be the Cake way to do that?

### Sample code

```
/* Model Variable.php */
class Variable extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = 'Test';
}


/* Model Test.php */
class Test extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = 'Study';
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
            'Variable' => array(
                'className' => 'variable',
                'joinTable' => 'tests_to_variables',
                'foreignKey' => 'test_id',
                'associationForeignKey' => 'variable_id',
                'with' => 'TestsToVariables',
            ),
        );
}

/* in baked TestsController.php */
$variables = $this->Test->Variable->find('list');
$this->set(compact('variables'));


/* in edit.ctp, the baked view */
echo $this->Form->input('Variable');
```

Answer (score 0):

Cake `Form::input()` has options for multi select, it also auto fills the values and selects previously saved data.

How does this not fit your needs, Have you even tried what is explained in the book?

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#creating-form-elements

Comment: Yes, I *even* tried the book (updated with the canonical example which I also tried of course) ;-) and about twenty Stackoverflow questions, as well as [this page](http://mrphp.com.au/blog/working-habtm-form-data-cakephp). Based on what model relation does the FormHelper auto-fill previously saved data in a multi-select? In the codebase for FormHelper I had the impression that multiple selects are supposed to work only with HABTM. I'm sorry, it may be hard to believe that this is not obvious to me.